# How can I include esi tags into main esi tag?

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, esi

I use esi and Varnish as caching proxy server in my project. The main block has ttl with 1 hour and several blocks into with ttl 10 minutes inside. Is it possible to include esi tags into main esi tag like described below?

> main.html.twig

```
    <esi:include src="/?action=menu/topBar"/>
    <esi:remove>
        {% include('partials/header/topBar.html.twig') %}
    </esi:remove>
```

> topBar.html.twig

```
    <esi:include src="/?action=index/extraLink" />
    <esi:remove>
        {% include('partials/header/extraLink.html.twig') %}
    </esi:remove>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to process ESI recursively. It's all just a matter of how your VCL is configured.

I see you're using Twig to render the ESI tags. I'm going to assume you're using the Symfony framework to process those Twig templates. If so, the solution is quite simple.

### ESI , Twig & Symfony

Please have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/esi.html first.

Symfony has a `render` function for Twig that processes controller routes as an internal subrequest and returns the HTML directly. That's an alternative to your `{% include %}` call.

But the cool thing is that Symfony also has a `render_esi` function for Twig. This will take a controller route and automatically output it as an *ESI tag* with the necessary `src` attribute.

Symfony validates whether or not it sits behind a Varnish server that supports ESI. It does this using a handshaking process. If it turns out that the ESI validation didn't succeed, it will fallback to the typical `render` behavior and just return the HTML as an internal subrequest.

> This behavior is identical to your Twig scripts where you use both `<exi:include />` and `<esi:remove />` as a fallback. The `render_esi` function handles this in a more efficient way.
>
> If your Symfony installation doesn't support the `render_esi` function, please install the following Composer package: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/twig-bridge

### ESI validation handshake

To make sure Symfony can do the correct validation, the following happens behind the scenes:

- Varnish sends a `Surrogate-Capability` header to announce it offers ESI support
- Symfony looks for that header and if it finds it, it sends back a `Surrogate-Control` header to indicate to Varnish that it too can handle ESI
- Varnish looks for that header, and if it finds it, it starts processing ESI

Here's an example of these headers:

- Varnish sends this one: `Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0`
- Symfony sends this one: `Surrogate-Control: content="ESI/1.0"`

### The VCL you need to make this happen

As described on https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/varnish.html, you can use the following VCL snippet to process the VCL:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    // Add a Surrogate-Capability header to announce ESI support.
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    // Check for ESI acknowledgement and remove Surrogate-Control header
    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}
```

### Recursive ESI

The Twig syntax you need is the following:

main.html.twig:

```
{% render_esi("/?action=menu/topBar") %}
```

topBar.html.twig:

```
{% render_esi("/?action=index/extraLink") %}
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#render-esi for more information about `render_esi`.